# In R, how can i calculate how much time has left between 2 times?

Tags: r

For example:

if I have

```
x <- "2016-11-23 16:22:03 IST"
y <- "2016-11-23 16:28:29 IST"
```

how can I calculate how much time has left between them?

Comment: First, convert the characters to datetime objects, then take the difference between the two. Could be `diff(lubridate::ymd_hms(c(x, y)))`. But there are other options.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x) -  as.POSIXct(y)` or `difftime(as.POSIXct(x), as.POSIXct(y))` ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x <- strptime("2016-11-23 16:22:03 IST", format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
y <- strptime("2016-11-23 16:28:29 IST", format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

y-x
#Time difference of 6.433333 mins
```

Comment: Please avoid answering duplicated questions. I understand you have answered before it was marked as dupe. Simple search for "r date time difference" would give many many already existing posts on this topic.